# What happens first when you login or logout from the system in Linux

Tags: linux

I was asked this question from my friend that

> when you login our logout from a Linux based system then what all
>   process run and in which sequence?

Being a **noob in Linux** and not into real system admin kind of job, so it was difficult for me to answer. Is there any particular tutorial on such concepts or can somebody explain what exactly happens while logging in or logging out from the Linux System?

Assume it is console terminal not GUI.

Comment: This is better suited at super user or linux stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux, the flow of control during a boot is from BIOS, to boot loader, to kernel. The kernel then starts the scheduler (to allow multi-tasking) and runs the first userland (i.e. outside kernel space) program Init (which is mostly responsible to run startup scripts for each runlevel), at which point the kernel goes idle unless called externally.

init (short for initialization) is a program for Unix-based computer operating systems that spawns all other processes. It runs as a daemon and typically has PID 1. The boot loader starts the kernel and the kernel starts init. If one were to delete init without a replacement, the system would encounter a kernel panic on the next reboot.

When init starts, it reads a file called inittab, usually located in /etc. This file tells init which programs should be run under which conditions. Not only does init run the startup scripts that bring the rest of the system up, but init also takes care of shutting the system down. Commonly, init will start a program called "getty" to spawn a new terminal (or tty), and "login" for login prompt. This configuration is set inside inittab. In recent version of linux, inittab is replaced with /etc/init/*.conf and scripts inside /etc/init.d/

**On shutdown**, Init is called to close down all user space functionality in a controlled manner, again via scripted directions, following which Init terminates and the Kernel executes its own shutdown.

[See Linux startup process Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process)

Login: **Getty** is the process which will take care of complete login process.

1. Init creates the getty process
2. getty process initiates login command
3. login command try to check user credentials
4. getty creates user shell process
5. getty read shell property files
6. getty provides you with PS1 prompt

On **logout**, the shell program exits and we return to *step 1*.

[See login process at this website 1](http://www.linuxnix.com/2013/09/how-login-process-work-in-linux.html)

[See login process at this website 2](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hllogin.html)

Comment: :He is asking about login and logout process not about boot process

Comment: Those links are really helpful but still logout process is not explained in both links. I am waiting and searching over net meanwhile :)

Comment: I think, the answer from sujin is very good, because it delivers a bit more info, which still should be known by each linux user, who wants to look inside linux.

Comment: For boot, login, and shutdown, this link also helpful http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_04_02.html, however, shutdown is not elaborated